# Configurar visual studio code para que muestre la apertura y cierre de etiquetas html

Tags: visual-studio

tengo un problema, visual code no me muestra la apertura y cierre de etiquetas, cada que doy click unicamente marca todas las etiquetas con el mismo nombre, más no muestra la apertura y cierre de determinada etiqueta...

Comment: también sigo este problema y no he logrado resolverlo. Ayuda por favor

Comment: pudiste solucionar esto? de verdad me gustaría empezar a usar vscode pero sin esta opción me resulta muy molesto :-(

Answer (score 2):

entra en `Archivo >> Preferencias >> Configuracion` y en tu archivo de configuracion de usuario agregas `"editor.matchBrackets": false` debe quedar algo como:

```
{
    "sublimeTextKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true, //No se te olvide la coma
    "editor.matchBrackets": false //Linea nueva
}
```

Solo reinicia el programa y deberia quedar.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de mucho estar investigando encontré con la configuración indicada.

En el archivo de configuración agregas la siguiente linea:

`"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false`

O si prefires incluso cambiar el color de las que se resalta las etiquetas agrega este bloque:

`"highlight-matching-tag.style": { 
       "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 191, 63, 0.20)" 
    }, 
   "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false`